# Is it possible to define a ReactJS Mixin method that can be overridden in a React Component?

Tags: reactjs

The Facebook ReactJS library has strict rules about [which component methods can be overridden and how](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0c6bee049efb63585fb88c995de788cefc18b789/src/core/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L47). Unless it's [specifically allowed](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0c6bee049efb63585fb88c995de788cefc18b789/src/core/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L407), we cannot redefine a method.

For my custom mixins how can I update the SpecPolicy if I have a method I want to allow to be overridden? Is this even possible?

This example is a bit contrived but it should get the point across. Say I have the mixin below which is trying to provide a default `renderItem` method, intended to be overridden if necessary. When I attempt to render the component `<Hello ... />` I get an `Invariant Violation` error. You can find [a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/xz9RR/).

```
var MyMixin = {
    render: function () {
        return this.renderItem();
    },
    renderItem: function () {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
};

var Hello = React.createClass({
    mixins: [MyMixin],
    renderItem: function() {
        return <div>Hey {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't possible right now. It's likely that a future version of React will have mixins that take advantage of ES6 classes and will be a bit more flexible. See here for a proposal:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-future/blob/master/01%20-%20Core/02%20-%20Mixins.js

Comment: Nothing that ES6 classes does that not possible now, i would say, reactjs mixin is not implemented in a way so it can be extended. in feature it may change.

Answer (score 8):

You could just use something like [jQuery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to extend the object that's passed to `React.createClass`, instead of using a mixin - this would allow you to still use Mixins when you want, and use this method when you need to ([JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jserndqt/)):

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var MyMixin = {
    render: function () {
        return this.renderItem();
    },
    renderItem: function () {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
};

var Hello = React.createClass($.extend(MyMixin, {
    renderItem: function() {
        return <div>Hey {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
}));

React.renderComponent(<Hello name="World" />, document.body);
```

Comment: IMHO, this is very much against the [mixin principle](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins)  as introduced by React itself. I admit that this solution refers to the problem domain, but mixins in React are a good example of [how one should rethink composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). You certainly can hack your way around it (e.g. as suggested above), but you should be aware of the pitfalls.

Comment: Yes - all good points! React does strongly prefer composition over inheritance, but this is one way you can approach both cases if you like, as requested in the question.

Comment: and just to be clear - I think @LukasBünger is right - you should try and use composition over inheritance. Instead of overriding methods, think of mixins as helpers that add functions to make it easy to reuse functionality. For example, instead of overriding `render`, include a mixin that adds helper functions for rendering, like `renderItem`, and `renderItemList`, and call those in your `render` method. A non trivial React app that duplicates hacker news, and uses these techniques [can be found here](https://github.com/insin/react-hn)

Comment: I partly have to redeem my comment from above. While it is certainly true that composition over inheritance is a concept that React encourages to use, it does look like inheritance in general is not something that is completely off the React world. Not in the near future at least: https://github.com/reactjs/react-future/blob/master/01%20-%20Core/02%20-%20Mixins.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this if you still want a default rednerItem implementation:

```
var MyMixin = {
  render: function () {
    return this.renderItem();
  },
  renderItem: function () {
    var customRender = this.customRenderItem;
    return customRender != undefined ? customRender() : <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
};

var Hello = React.createClass({
    mixins: [MyMixin],
    customRenderItem: function() {
      return <div>Hey {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The mixin has access to the component properties and state. You can have multiple implementations in the mixin and use the implement you need based on the properties/state.

Only thing you want to make sure that the components using the mixin have these properties/state or have a default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In situation, when i need to provide some properties to mixin, that depends on my react class, i make mixin as a function with needed arguments, that return mixin object

```
//mixin.js
module.exports = function mixin(name){
  return {
    renderItem(){
      return <span>name</span>
    }
  };
}

//react-class.js
var myMixin = require('mixin');
module.exports = React.createClass({
    mixins:[myMixin('test')],
    render(){
        return this.renderItem();
    }
});
//result
<span>test</test>
```